# PRAW: How can I continuously check for new reddit submissions (and perform action)

Tags: python-3.x, reddit, praw

Currently, the script I'm working on will look at the newest submission for a subreddit and return the flair from that post. But it will only do this once and ignore any new submissions while it is running.

How can I get this to continuously check in intervals and provide flairs for future incoming submissions?

Current code:

```
def subdata():

    for submission in subreddit.new(limit=1):
        flair = submission.link_flair_text

        return flair


subdata()
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49743797/python-praw-reddit-api-reliably-get-posts-as-they-are-posted/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# ... (creation of subreddit object, logging into Reddit, ...)

for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
  flair = submission.link_flair_text
  # call a function here that processes your flair
  custom_method(flair)

def custom_method(flair):
  print(flair)
```

When you are returning in a `for loop` the loop will be cancelled. You however want to continuously retrieve new submissions. It is not possible to return it.

**edit**: fixed some mistakes thanks jarhill0

Comment: `.submissions` is a function and needs to be called (i.e. `subreddit.stream.submissions():`).

Comment: In addition to that, PRAW explicitly [is not supported in a multithreaded environment](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/multiple_instances.html#multiple-threads).